# Take the mean of a series of lists and get the mean

Tags: python, pandas, list, mean, series

I am working with a series of strings. I pulled out the numbers from those strings and want to get the average. The problem seems to be that they are still strings and I am not sure how to turn each item in the list in the series into an integer and then take the mean.

```
list_series = added_df["Salary Estimate"].str.findall(r'\d+')
for index, value in list_series.items():
    for i in value:
        i = int(i)       
from statistics import mean
added_df['Average Salary'] = added_df['Salary Estimate'].map(mean)
```

I thought that I had converted them into integers, but I still get this error message:

> TypeError: can't convert type 'str' to numerator/denominator

Comment: Do `added_df['Salary Estimate'].astype(int)` instead to convert them all to `int`

Answer (score 2):

You can do `explode` then `groupby`

```
added_df["Salary Estimate mean"] = added_df["Salary Estimate"].str.findall(r'\d+').explode().astype(int).groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Or

```
added_df["Salary Estimate"].str.findall(r'\d+').apply(pd.Series).astype(int).mean(1)
```

Comment: please help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73222905/pandas-count-the-number-of-occurrence-of-all-matched-patterns-in-a-column